# how to warn against deleting folded subtree in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm editing content in emacs org-mode and using the header structure in both folded and unfolded modes. In editing, though, I'm worried I will accidentally delete a folded subtree containing content.

Is there a way to get org-mode to warn me before deleting a folded subtree containing hidden content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the following variables to protect hidden trees under some circumstances:

```
org-catch-invisible-edits
org-ctrl-k-protect-subtree
```

Note however that those will not protect hidden trees from being killed by, e.g., `C-w` (`kill-region`).

Comment: org-ctrl-k-protect-subtree is not working in the current emacs.